# geom_text different color labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with a categorical dataset of averages, modeled off of the following code:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(
    avg_sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width),
    avg_sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(avg_sepal_width, avg_sepal_length)) -> iris_avg
```

This provides me with the table:

| Species | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| setosa | avg_sepal_width | 3.428 |
| setosa | avg_sepal_length | 5.006 |
| versicolor | avg_sepal_width | 2.770 |
| versicolor | avg_sepal_length | 5.936 |
| virginica | avg_sepal_width | 2.974 |
| virginica | avg_sepal_length | 6.588 |

Working with this data, I cam creating a simple side-by-side bar chart using ggplot, as follows:

```
iris_avg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = 2)
```

I am trying to determine if there is a way for me to add a `color =`  parameter in the `geom_text` layer that would allow me to make the two different categories (length and width) different colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `color=name` to the text's `aes(.)`. If you do that by itself, it'll choose the same colors as used for `fill=` above it, rendering the text the same color as the bar on which they are placed; to fix that, use `scale_color_manual(values=..)` to specify the colors in a named-vector.

```r
iris_avg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = value, color = name), position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(avg_sepal_length="green", avg_sepal_width="black"))
```

[image]

(Though perhaps you can find colors that don't look at ghastly.)

Comment: For some reason, I kept placing it outside the `aes`. Thank you!